# Unable to connect to firebase real time database using datasnapshot

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and i am trying to get a datasnapshot for the location at the specified relative path.However, when i try to run the app i am getting the error like:

> com.google.firebase.database.Datasnapshot cannot be cast to java.lang.string

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my database connection code:

```
@Override
public void run() {

  ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
           TaskResult result= new TaskResult();
           result.setSuccess(true);
            result.setMessage("Successful");
           result.setResult(DataSnapshot);
            fireOnComplete(result);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull DatabaseError error) {

  }
});
```

I don't know what actually wrong with my code.

Comment: please add more code every method related

Comment: also add what are trying to do, if there are log then add

Comment: if you don't know then learn about debugging Android app https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Comment: `result.setResult(DataSnapshot);` can you use this `result.setResult(snapshot);`

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data) and indicate the exact data you want to get. Please respond with @AlexMamo